# "error: unknown type name 'GtkTooltips'" when trying to compile Glade 2.0 souce

Tags: gtk, glade, manjaro, texas-instruments

I am using Manjaro Linux and I need the [Glade](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libglade) 2.0 library as a dependency for [TILP](https://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/374/37480.html),
which will allow me to interface with my TI-84 calculator.

However when I try to compile [this particular version of Glade](https://github.com/Distrotech/libglade/releases/tag/LIBGLADE_2_0_1) from source I receive the following error:

```
In file included from glade-init.c:34:
glade-private.h:33:5: error: unknown type name 'GtkTooltips'
   33 |     GtkTooltips *tooltips; /* if not NULL, holds all tooltip info */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I would like to know how to go about fixing this issue or, alternatively, a better way to install Glade 2.0 or TILP on my system.